# Need to change one element from a document. - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to follow the documentation on mongoDB to change one element from an array, inside an array, inside an array.

This is my element

```
secciones: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3e"),
    subSeccion: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3f"),
        subSeccionItems: [
          "The witch jumps over the sleepy dog",
          "The witch jumps over the sleepy dog",
          "The dog eats"
          "The cat scratches"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem is that with this command it changes both occurrences of `The witch jumps over the sleepy dog, and I need just one to be changed:

```
db.pautas.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b37")}, {$set: {"criterios.secciones.$[id].subSeccion.$[id2].subSeccionItems.$[enun]": "The witch jumps over the sleepy dog"}}, { arrayFilters: [ { "id._id": ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3e")}, {"id2._id": ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3f")}, {"enun": "The elephant smells"}]})
```

Same command unformatted:

db.pautas.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b37")}, {$set: {"criterios.secciones.$[id].subSeccion.$[id2].subSeccionItems.$[enun]": "The witch jumps of the sleepy dog"}}, { arrayFilters: [ { "id._id": ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3e")}, {"id2._id": ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b3f")}, {"enun": "The elephant smells"}]})

Im using this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

**The command works, but changes both elements, I need just one to change**.

Regards.

**UPDATE**

Now with the answer from @willis I tried this query and got the same result. I saved some characters but didn't get the result I need, which is to change just **one** occurrence of the item in question.

```
db.pautas.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b37")}, {$set: {"criterios.secciones.$[].subSeccion.$[].subSeccionItems.$[enun]": "The witch jumps of the sleepy dog"}}, { arrayFilters: [ {"enun": "The elephant smells"}]})
```

Unformatted:

db.pautas.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5c6ee5d5e12e25dc1ab99b37")}, {$set: {"criterios.secciones.$[].subSeccion.$[].subSeccionItems.$[enun]": "The witch jumps of the sleepy dog"}}, { arrayFilters: [ {"enun": "The elephant smells"}]})

I'm still stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) should do what you want:

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document

```js
> db.test_coll.insert({arr: [{nested: ["hello", "hello", "goodbye"]}]})
> db.test_coll.update({"arr.nested": "hello"}, {$set: {"arr.$[].nested.$": "updated"}});
> db.test_coll.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c7344d94b434de8affa5b73"), "arr" : [ { "nested" : [ "updated", "hello", "goodbye" ] } ] }
```

Comment: with the $[] operator happens the same. I saved some characters on the query, but it still changes both elements.